# text box not being populated VB.net

Tags: vb.net

I am using vb.net to develop a simple desktop application. fillfeilds is a public function being called from another class.
The function is being called but the value of the textboxes doesn't change. But when I call  Button1_Click which in turn calls fillfeilds the routine works fine.

I would be most grateful if anyone could guide me as to what I am doing wrong as I do not understand this behavior.

Thanks.

> ```
> Public Sub fillFeilds()
>
>         FirstNamePri.Text = "lll"
>         FirstNamePri.Text = "lll"
>         LastNameAlt.Text = "kkkk"
>
>
>     End Sub
>
>
>     Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
>         FirstNamePri.Text = "lll"
>
>         fillFeilds()
>     End Sub
> ```

'class that calls fillfeild() function

> Public Class MainCust
>
> ```
>       Dim cust As New CustInfo
>     MainWindow.MainPanel.Controls.Add(cust)
>
>     Dim rec As New Customer
>
>     Dim dataArr As ArrayList = rec.getFirstCust()
>
>     Dim customer As New CustInfo
>     customer.fillFeilds(dataArr)
>
>
> End Sub
>
> End Class
> ```

Comment: Are you calling Button1_Click via code, or by actually clicking the button in the UI?  Can you show the code where you are showing the form and calling fillFeilds [sic]?

Comment: Show the code in the other class that is calling `fillFeilds`

Comment: @steveDog have added class file which call fillfeilds(). I am calling Button1_click by actually pressing the button. Had added it just to check if fill feild works

Comment: Is the MainWindow the class that contains your button1_click event?

Comment: @steve no CustInfo contain the button

Comment: Then, in your code above there is an error. The `fillFeilds` shown  doens't match to the expected signature used when you call customer.fillFeilds where you pass an ArrayList-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating two separate instances of `CustInfo`.  You are showing the first one but not the second one.  The second one, which is never shown is the one on which you are actually filling the fields.  Try this instead:

```
Dim cust As New CustInfo
MainWindow.MainPanel.Controls.Add(cust)
Dim rec As New Customer
Dim dataArr As ArrayList = rec.getFirstCust()
cust.fillFeilds(dataArr)
```

Comment: wow..thanks man your a genius. I have been tying to figure this out for a couple of hours now. But if you could just explain again what I was doing wrong. I don't understand why it matters that you have 2 instances of the same class..then why wouldn't one work and other doesn't.

Comment: An instance of a class is called an "object".  Every time you call `New`, it instantiates a whole new object.  Each object is completely independent from the other objects (unless they explicitly share data through globals or shared fields).  So for instance, if I created two different baskets, and I gave you one of them, and I kept one for myself, and then I put eggs in the basket I was holding, the basket that you are holding would still be empty.  They are both baskets (the class), but they are two completely separate objects.

Answer (score 0):

You may have a threading issue if your calling from another class which is on another thread? Maybe? but i would of though it'll throw and exception. Is it being called on another thread?

Comment: No its just another class that calls it